# How to get value from td hidden field through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic table. I am trying to get a value of a hidden field which is `order_id`, but I am getting only the first `id`. If I click on the 3rd or 4th etc button I still get the `order_id` of the first td. Below is my code :

```
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="hid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="button" id="sends" value="Send" onclick="sendemails();">
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
    function sendemails(){
        var sends = $('#sends').val();
        var hid = $('#hid').val();
        alert(hid);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, most likely it's because you are using the same ID multiple times, which you can't, ID's need to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another solution

```
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="hid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="button" id="sends" value="Send" onclick="sendemails(<?php echo $id; ?>);">
    </td>
</tr>
<script>
function sendemails(hid){
    alert(hid);
}
</script>
```

And note that attribute "id" had to be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are presumably repeating that row in the table, which will result in the id of both the button and input being repeated throughout the page, which is invalid. You need to use classes, attach your events in JS and then traverse the DOM to find the related hidden input. Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="hid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="sends" value="Send" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.sends', function() {
        var sends = $(this).val();
        var hid = $(this).prev().val();
        alert(hid);
    });
});
```

Note that I used a delegated event handler as you stated the table is dynamically generated.

Comment: I tried it and i face this issue            Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
vieworders.php:318 Uncaught ReferenceError: sendemails is not defined

Comment: Now i get this issue: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ vieworders.php:3336c.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.1:26L @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.1:33
vieworders.php:318 Uncaught ReferenceError: sendemails is not definedonclick @ vieworders.php:318`

Comment: 1) You need to remove the `onclick` attribute from the button 2) What version of jQuery are you using? If it's less than 1.7 you need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `"this"` in `onclick` event like this: `onclick="sendemails(this);"` and get this on your function.

Try:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="hid" value="hid">
        <input type="button" id="sends" value="Send" onclick="sendemails(this);">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
    function sendemails(btn){
        var sends = btn.value;
        var hid = $("#" + btn.id).closest("td").find("#hid").val()
        alert(hid)
    }
</script>
```